# How to apply padding to HMAC-MD5 result length while calculating OTP?

Tags: cryptography, md5, hmac, javacard, one-time-password

While generating One Time Password, i used hmac-md5 algorithm(with respect to RFC 2104) and the hmac result is 128 bits. When hmac-SHA1 algorithm is used, the result will be 160 bits. I need to apply padding to my hmac-md5 result to make 20 byte. Which values should i use for padding?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about cryptographic practices

Comment: I tagged cryptography. What should i do to relate with topic?

Comment: SO is for programming quesetions (including crypto programs) but not for crypto best practices.  Perhaps crypto.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Yes, that's the perfect place to explain that this is not an OTP :)

Answer (score 1):

> I need to apply padding to my hmac-md5 result to make 20 byte. Which values should i use for padding?

Apply another iteration of the hash on the existing output. Then, use the leftmost *l-bits* needed. This is similar to moder KDFs when stretching is needed.

Visually, it might look like:

```
[            hash = HMAC(message)            ][ HMAC(hash) ]
```